# JS appendChild() to a <div> in <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to avoid the below issue by making my *div* a direct child of *body* and appending a *select* to the *div*, but am not able to achieve the same results when the *div* is a child of a *form* within *body* (either when appending to the *div* or to the *form*).

I am just making a **drop-down table (*select* element)** that is added to the web page when the user clicks a button. The drop-down *select* shows when the *div* is the direct child of *body*, but not when it is a child of a *form* that is a child of *body*. When the button is clicked using the below method, the dropdown appears for like 0.25s and then the page returns to the original layout. The same occurs when trying to append directly to the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--text_index.html-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Drop Down Menu to HTML w/ JS on Button Click</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form-button">
        <div id="user-area">
            <button id="dropdown-button">Add a dropdown menu!</button><br /><br />      
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="test_script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the JS is shown below. The console returns no error but the *select* element does not remain in the browser window.

```
let materialArray = ['Select Your Material:',
                    'Kryptonite',
                    'Odium',
                    'Quartz'];

let formButton = document.getElementById('form-button');
let divUserArea = document.getElementById('user-area');
let dropdownBtn = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');

/***********************************************************************/

/****BEGIN LOOP W/ BUTTON CLICK AND NAMED FUNCTION****/

//NOTE: YOU CANNOT appendChild() ON A <DIV> INSIDE A <FORM>.
////IF YOU CAN THEN THERE IS SOME LOGIC THAT I AM MISSING.
////YOU CANNOT appendChild() DIRECTLY ON A FORM EITHER.

let newSelect = document.createElement("select");
let newOption = [];

function onClickDropdownBtn () {
    for (let i = 0; i < materialArray.length; i++) {
        newOption[i] = document.createElement("option"); //create the new option for the new HTML select element
        newOption[i].text = materialArray[i]; //add the appropriate text to the new option
        newSelect.add(newOption[i], i); //add the completed option to the HTML select element
    }
    divUserArea.appendChild(newSelect); //also tried formButton.appendChild(newSelect); and got same 
                                          result                       
    return true;
}

dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click', onClickDropdownBtn);

if (onClickDropdownBtn === false) {
    newSelect.style.display = 'hidden';
    dropdownBtn.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    newSelect.style.display = 'block';
    dropdownBtn.style.display = 'hidden';
}

/****END LOOP W/ BUTTON CLICK AND NAMED FUNCTION ****/
```

Is there a way to append to the *div* inside the *form*, or to the *form* directly?

Thanks!

For gits and shiggles, here is the CSS. Maybe the issue is here?

```
select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried event.preventDefault() on the button? I believe your form is just reloading the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a `<button>` inside a form, [the default `type` is **submit**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type), which makes the page "refresh" (that's why you only see your dropdown for a second).

You can either change your button type, like this:

```html
<button type='button' id="dropdown-button">Add a dropdown menu!</button>
```

Or you can add the `event.PreventDefault()` in your click function to avoid the form submission, like this:

```js
function onClickDropdownBtn (event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < materialArray.length; i++) {
    newOption[i] = document.createElement("option"); //create the new option for the new HTML select element
    newOption[i].text = materialArray[i]; //add the appropriate text to the new option
    newSelect.add(newOption[i], i); //add the completed option to the HTML select element
  }
  divUserArea.appendChild(newSelect); //also tried formButton.appendChild(newSelect); and got same

  event.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
```

That will keep your dropdown component in the page and you can go from there.

Comment: Thank you Bruno for the detailed and very helpful answer.

Comment: If that solved your question, I would be glad if you could accept this as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Forms have the default behaviour of reloading the page (they evolved in an era before SPAs). Your code works just fine, except that it also reloads the page and you lose the state (in your case, the select element).

Just change `onClickDropdownBtn()` to

```
function onClickDropdownBtn (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
```

and it should be ready to go!